# JAVA/CXF Validate JSON at runtime against schema (Draft 4)

Tags: java, validation, rest, cxf, jackson

I am building a RESTful service using CXF and Jackson. I need to validate JSON data against json schema (draft 4). I think I should validate it before deserialization.

I have gone through https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator. I want to use this validator but how can I plug-in this in my application? Should I override JacksonJsonProvider?

Answer (score 0):

You should provide schemaLocation to your JSONProvider. You can simply provide it through your configuration file (context.xml).

I used it sometime back but faced issue with schemaLocation. My provider was unable to load Schema. In that case, you can override your provider and set your location map yourself.